# JPA relation OneToMany

Tags: jpa

I was thinking that I understand the relations. But now.. Im not sure. I have a problem to add correct annotations.

I have classes Members and Relations.

In Relations

```
private GT_Member Mother;

private GT_Member Father;

private List<GT_Member> children;
```

One Member can be in several Relations as Mother or Father (reference to his sex) but he can be only in One relation as child.

I thought annotate Mother and Father as @OneToMany.

But I'm not sure if I can annotate List as @OneToOne ??

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem in modeling the correct entity-relationship model for your database schema and visualizing your ORM (Object Relationship Model).

Rather than starting with classes Members and Relations, please first see what are the dominant data-entities in your system. And how would they be related to each other.
Personally I do not think Relation would be a good JPA entity.
Member looks more like a good entity and could embody the relations
Assuming one Father and one Mother, One to Many seems wrong but as a father or mother can have many children, the correct annotation should be @ManyToOne.

Children is definitely OneToMany, and yes you can annotate the List children as @OneToMany.

Member could have the following properties:

```
@Entity
   public class Member implements Serializable{
    @ManyToOne
    private Member mother;
    @ManyToOne
    private Member father;
    @OnetoMany
    private List<Member> children;
 }
```

This solves both your use cases and in this simple example Relation class is not needed.
hope this helps.

Comment: Employment of Relation entity is because I want to save information about status of relation. Donc I will store information about all married etc. Entity relation has other fields like type (neutral, married, fiance etc...).

Comment: hmm that seems like an interesting problem to model within an entity. the information you provide the more helpful it is. But even in this case you can avoid having a separate relation entity, by having this multi-value filed called  marital-status (single, married, engaged) and then another field of type Member partner; this could be null (if marital-status is single), an actual Member (is marital-status is married or engaged).

Answer (score 0):

Employment of  Relation entity is because I want to  save information about status of relation. Donc I will store information about  all married etc.   Entity relation has other fields like type (neutral, married, fiance etc...).

Comment: Please post answers only in this section